# Logging from base and extended classes with log4j?

Tags: inheritance, logging, log4j, slf4j

I'm using slf4j with log4j and I have the following situation:

```
package x.y.z.base;
public class FTPOperationsBase {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FTPOperationsBase.class);
    protected FTPClient ftp;
    // some more fields

    public void connect() {
        ...
        // log all connect exceptions
    }
    public void disconnect() {
        ...
        // log all disconnect exceptions
    };
}
```

As it can be seen, package is *x.y.z.base*. Now I have several classes which extend this base class (these classes are currently in packages x.y.z.classA, x.y.z.clasB,... etc).

I want **separate log file for each of these classes**, as they act as separate modules. But what I also want is to somehow put log from base class to these separate logs, depending on which class is being used, that is **I don't want log form base class in all logs if only one subclass is executing**. For example, if I have extended class:

```
public class FTPExtendedClass1 
extends FTPOperationsBase {
    public void doSomething() {...}
}
```

and make the following code sequence:

```
FTPExtendedClass1 obj1 = new FTPExtendedClass1();
obj1.connect();
obj1.doSomething();
obj1.disconnect();
```

I'd like to have the log file for this case as follows:

- possible info/warnings/errors from connect()
- possible info/warnings/errors from doSomething()
- possible info/warnings/errors from disconnect()

This should be the case for all extended classes, where *doSomething()* is class-specific method.  Any way to organize packages / configure log4j for this behavior ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create different Appender in your log4j.xml.

One for each different class.

```
<logger name="yourBaseClassName" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="BasefileAppender" />
</logger>

<appender name="BasefileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
<param name="File" value="/path/yourfile.log"/>

    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="yourExtendedClassName" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="ExtendOnefileAppender" />
</logger>

<appender name="ExtendOnefileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
<param name="File" value="/path/ExtendOnefileAppender.log"/>

    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

then in each of your class (Base and extended) you do:

```
Logger mylogger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName())
```

I don't think it cover your second requirement (But what I also want is to somehow put log from base class to these separate logs, depending on which class is being used)

but its a start... ;-)   with this you should be able to log in different file based on the name of the class.

Hope it help

Comment: Well, as you said, this is not quite the solution I was looking for, and I was already aware of this kind of configuration. I think I'll just propagate exceptions via base-class method declaration, or pass logger reference, either will work. Anyway, +1 for taking the time to answer question ;)